# How to remove more than one index in json_encode?

Tags: php

I have data with key value pair, this data will be used to plot in Highchart graph with time series data. I have data format as below

```
{"EventTS":1497033900000,"MainsPower":204},
{"EventTS":1497034800000,"MainsPower":204},
{"EventTS":1497035700000,"MainsPower":204}
```

but Highchart requires data in below format

```
{1497033900000,204},
{1497034800000,204},
{1497035700000,204}
```

I can not use foreach loop as data is more than 50 thousand. Kindly suggest way to convert data without using foreach loop in php

Comment: you mean `[[1497033900000,204],[1497034800000,204],[1497035700000,204]]`

Comment: Firstly your output is not valid JS. HighCharts expects an nested array. Secondly, there's no way to do this on the existing data format without a loop. Your best solution would be to change the way your PHP is generating the data, but you haven't shown us that so this question is unanswerable.

Comment: If you really want to have your data in your desired format without using a loop, you should generate your data IN THAT FORMAT int the first place. There's no way to do that without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You **need** a loop to change it, or change your own code to format it differently.

In php before json_encode() add something like:

```
foreach($json as $item) {
    $array[] = array_values($item);
}
$json[0] = $array;
```

And it will be stored as madalin ivascu wrote in the comment